# Python OAuth1.0 using consumer key and RSA private key

Tags: python, rsa, oauth-1.0a

I require to hit a URL and get the status of the URL (200 ok or not).
For this we need to authenticate using OAuth1.0 , we have a consumerkey and RSA-256 private key.
I am able to hit this endpoint through postman, looking for python script to do this operation.
Tried using this, but instaed of client secret we need to use RSA private key
so looking for the correct syntax.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
  
CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxx"

ourSession = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
```